# error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'tooltip.js'

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm

npm tooltip.js package has a default class Export named Tooltip.
but when i import that class in my ts file and print in it says undefined? whats the cause of this problem?

Comment: you need to install the type definition file for tooltip as well

Comment: It does not seem to be using a default export https://github.com/mkay581/tooltip-js/blob/master/dist/tooltip.js

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Typescript, you need a type declaration file for tooltip.js.

The reason is that Typescript requires you to include type information of variables in the code. JavaScript code doesn't have this type information, so when you import a JavaScript code file into a Typescript code file, you need a .d.ts file to help Typescript work with that JavaScript code.

Now, if it were your own JavaScript code, you could simply edit it and add type annotations to comply wit Typescript, but you shouldn't be editing 3rd party JavaScript libraries. Some libraries include their type declarations. For those that don't, you either need to write a .d.ts file yourself or use one open-sourced by someone else. Turns out, the latter is quite feasible. Type declarations of many popular 3rd party JavaScript files can be found at [DefinitelyTyped](http://definitelytyped.org/).

Also, look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36128234/2691993).

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue but for different library `jspdf`. In my case, my `tsconfig.app.json` file had a **jspdf** included in the types array for compilerOptions.

> I'm not sure how that got there but removing it fixed the issue.

I basically changed the src/tsconfig.app.json file from

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
  "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
  // "allowJs":true,
  "baseUrl": "./",
  "module": "es2015",
   "types": [
           "node","jspdf"
           ]
   },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
  ]
}
```

to

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
  "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
  // "allowJs":true,
  "baseUrl": "./",
  "module": "es2015",
   "types": [
           "node"
           ]
   },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts",
  ]
}
```